# Issue with datetime.datetime.strptime on *NIX

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, amazon-linux

Context: I am running this code on Python3.6.8 on Amazon Linux 2

I am having an issue with the datetime.datetime.strptime method throwing the following error:

`ValueError: time data '2019-11-22T08:00:14-08:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'`

I do not get this error when executing the same block of code on my Windows System. I believe it may be caused by the known compatibility issue of the %z directive on *Nix, but I was under the impression that this was fixed for version >3.2.

Was I misguided on this? If so, what is the general work around if I wanted to be able to parse timezone information from a timestamp on Amazon Linux 2?

```py
def parse_pd_time_strings(timeString):
    return dt.strptime(timeString,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

**Solution:**
This issue appears to be fixed on Python 3.7+. For my purposes updating the Python version is an acceptable option.

If you have a work around that works for users for whom updating is not an option, I'd still be fascinated to read it.

Comment: can you post some sample code that is throwing this error?

Comment: Added code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this issue appears to be fixed on Python 3.7+. For my purposes updating the Python version is an acceptable option.

If you have a work around that works for users for whom updating is not an option, I'd still be fascinated to read it.